# How to pass the result of a command to docker inspect format (Golang template)?

Tags: docker, format, inspect, go-templates

I'm trying to pass the result of a command to the golang template of another command:

> **container_id**=$(docker ps -aqf "name=*container_name*")
>
> docker network inspect --format='{{range $i,$container:= .Containers}} {{if eq $container.Name (print 'gateway_' **$container_id**)}} {{$container.IPv4Address}} {{end}} {{end}}' *network*

The purpose is to get the container IP Address in the specific network interface, which is not available with a simple

> docker inspect *container_id*

Thank you for any help.

Comment: To pass a variable, you'll need to use double quotes and then escape all the special characters, particularly the `$` that you don't want expanded by the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `"` and escape all other `$` used by golang template. The following command will print IPv4 Address by container name on interface `bridge`:

```
$> export CONTAINER_NAME=backstabbing_feynman
$> docker network inspect --format="{{range \$id, \$container := .Containers}} {{if eq \$container.Name \"$CONTAINER_NAME\"}} {{\$id}} -> {{\$container.IPv4Address}} {{end}}{{end}}"  bridge
3a77b8fe2d14fb527a8c634fdaa46121672daf827c7fad0aabad1de37877e03e -> 192.168.0.4/20
```

Using `container_id` will be the similiar.